# Python Groupby and Aggregate by 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, aggregate

I would like to summarize by dataset based on two columns and get both the 'sum' and 'count' of these columns. I know how to get the 'sum' and 'count' of the columns separately, for example:

```
summary = df.groupby(['country','item', "date", 'msgtype'], as_index=False)['size', 'turnover'].sum()
```

But I want to be able to do it in one line if possible, without having to do merges etc.

I tried to do this:

```
summary = df.groupby(['country','item', "date", 'order'], as_index=False).agg({(['size', 'weight']) : ['sum' , 'count']})
```

But I get the error:

```
unhashable type: 'list'
```

So I'm not too sure what to do. If anyone could help me with this problem I would really appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```py
# aggregate size and weight by country, item, date and order
summary = df.groupby(['country','item', "date", 'order'])[['size', 'weight']].agg(['sum' , 'count'])
# flatten column names
summary.columns = [f"{x}_{y}" for x,y in summary.columns]
# make groupers columns
summary = summary.reset_index()
```

It groups by country, item, date and order and aggregates size and weight columns by their respective sum and counts.